# Capture.output disregarding console size in r

Tags: r, matrix, export-to-csv, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to use capture.output to save a confusion matrix as follows:

```
capture.output(result, file = "F:/Results/result.txt")
```

- My confusion matrix has a lot of columns
- When I save the file, it breaks the columns as it does in the RStudio console.
- If I make the console bigger, it has enough space and does not break
- My question is:

**Is it possible to have Capture.output ignore the console size and assume it's as big as possible (so it doesn't break things apart)?**

If you want to try it on my specific data, I put it here as an .rds file:
https://upload.uni-jena.de/data/5f1045c6c0da81.96434142/result.rds

Here's how it looks:

In a small console (broken apart):

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

           Reference
Prediction  ATCC25922 DSM1576
  ATCC25922         2       0
  DSM1576           0       2
  DSM3871           0       0
  DSM429            0       0
  DSM498            0       0
  DSM499            0       0
  DSM501            0       0
  DSM613            0       0
  DSM8696           0       0
  DSM9031           0       0
  Gr02              0       0
  Gr05              0       0
  Gr06              0       0
  Gr07              0       0
  Gr09              0       1
  Pak56             0       0
  Pak57             0       0
  Pak58             1       0
  Pak64             0       0
  Pak66             0       0
           Reference
Prediction  DSM3871 DSM429
  ATCC25922       0      0
  DSM1576         0      1
  DSM3871         2      0
  DSM429          0      2
  DSM498          1      0
  DSM499          0      0
  DSM501          0      0
  DSM613          0      0
  DSM8696         0      0
  DSM9031         0      0
  Gr02            0      0
  Gr05            0      0
  Gr06            0      0
  Gr07            0      0
  Gr09            0      0
  Pak56           0      0
  Pak57           0      0
  Pak58           0      0
  Pak64           0      0
  Pak66           0      0
           Reference
Prediction  DSM498 DSM499
  ATCC25922      0      0
  DSM1576        0      0
  DSM3871        0      0
  DSM429         0      0
  DSM498         0      0
  DSM499         0      3
  DSM501         0      0
  DSM613         0      0
  DSM8696        0      0
  DSM9031        0      0
  Gr02           0      0
  Gr05           0      0
  Gr06           0      0
  Gr07           1      0
  Gr09           1      0
  Pak56          0      0
  Pak57          0      0
  Pak58          1      0
  Pak64          0      0
  Pak66          0      0
...
```

In a large console (in one piece):

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

           Reference
Prediction  ATCC25922 DSM1576 DSM3871 DSM429 DSM498 DSM499 DSM501 DSM613 DSM8696 DSM9031 Gr02 Gr05 Gr06 Gr07 Gr09 Pak56 Pak57 Pak58 Pak64 Pak66
  ATCC25922         2       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  DSM1576           0       2       0      1      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  DSM3871           0       0       2      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  DSM429            0       0       0      2      0      0      1      0       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  DSM498            0       0       1      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  DSM499            0       0       0      0      0      3      0      0       0       1    0    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0
  DSM501            0       0       0      0      0      0      2      0       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  DSM613            0       0       0      0      0      0      0      3       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  DSM8696           0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       3       0    0    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0
  DSM9031           0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       0       2    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     1
  Gr02              0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    3    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  Gr05              0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    2    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  Gr06              0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    1    2    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
  Gr07              0       0       0      0      1      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    1    0     0     1     0     0     0
  Gr09              0       1       0      0      1      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    1    0    1     0     1     0     1     0
  Pak56             0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     3     0     0     0     0
  Pak57             0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     1     0     0
  Pak58             1       0       0      0      1      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    1    0     0     0     1     1     0
  Pak64             0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1     0
  Pak66             0       0       0      0      0      0      0      0       0       0    0    0    0    1    0     0     0     1     0     2
```

Comment: Have you tried `as.matrix()` and then `write.table()`

Comment: Yes. It only keeps part of the output (the conf.table itself) I want ALL the output: confusion matrix, overall stats, by group stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `options(width = 100)` to enlarge the maximum number of characters on a line used in printing objects on the console.

```
options(width = 100)
capture.output(result, file = "F:/Results/result.txt")
```

**Note:** Don't resize the console window after setting `options(width = 100)`. Some R consoles automatically change the value when they are resized.